Brake judder - front or rear?
Vehicle is a 2011 Hyundai. It's had slight juddering while braking for a few years already, but recently it's gotten significantly worse.
The juddering is noticeable at speeds above 30km/h or 20 mph, is felt pretty much exclusively in the pedal, and not in the steering wheel, seats, etc.
Since it seems to be coming from the right side of the car, I took a look at the brakes there:
Front


Rear


To me the fronts look alright, there's plenty of pad left on both sides and the wear is even. The rears look pretty bad, the contact area on the rotor seems pretty small, and the wear is uneven - see 2nd picture above - could be seized guide pins I think.
So it seems to me that the rears definitely need service and the (underlying cause of the) uneven wear may well be the cause of the judder - does that sound reasonable, or should I do some further diagnosing before buying parts?

When diagnosing a symptom with an unknown cause, wise and frugal mechanics will fix what they know is bad before committing to any other repairs. This can simplify and focus the diagnosis by eliminating known good parts from further consideration as a possible cause.

A 2011 Hyundai is almost 14yrs old and how many miles? When was the last brake service performed, along with completely flushing out old brake fluid with new and bleeding the system? The rears are probably not working to brake and may be  overloading the front brakes, creating the juddering. The rear brakes may need overhauling, using new parts (machining both rotors for new surfaces or replacement,  new brake pads, new caliper slide pins, etc). Worse case scenario are two new/rebuilt brake calipers to fully restore rear braking for effective four wheel braking.
